# Question about logic and intervals

Tags: logic

If  $x>2$
does that mean that $x\ge=0?$
Or is this unnecessary since $x\ge0$ means that there is a value of $x$ that lies between $[0,2)$ and does not lie in the first one.
So, is the equality correct here?

Comment: Consider $x=3$. Here $x>2$ yet also $x\ge 0$ and there is no value of $x$ between $[0,2)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a case where one needs to be very clear exactly what you are asking.

Are you asking:  If we know that the number $x > 2$ then do we know that $x \ge 0$?  The answer to that is yes.  If $x > 2$ then $x\ge 0$ because $2 > 0$ and "$>$ is transitive and $x > 2 > 0$ and and so $x > 0$ and so $x \ge 0$.

In this case $x > 2$ is a stronger statement than $x \ge 0$.  Just like "Henry is a green frog who likes ice cream" is a stronger statement than "Henry is an animal who likes some kind of food".

Or are you asking if you have a set of solutions of all $x$ so that $x > 0$ (in other words the interval $(2, \infty)$) would that include the solution set of all solutions of all $x$ so that $x \ge 0$ (in other words the interval $[0, \infty)$. In this case the answer is no.  The set of all possible answer for $x\ge 0$ is a bigger and weaker set of answer than $x > 2$.

So what exactly is your question:

Are you trying to find out facts about $x$ if $x > 2$ (in which case, yes, $x \ge 0$ and $(2, \infty) \subset [0, \infty)$).

Or are you discussing entire solution sets where $x >2$ are all potential solutions does that mean all $x \ge 0$ are also potential solutions (in which case, no, if $x > 2$ it is not true that $0 \le x < 2$ and $[0\infty) \not \subset (2, \infty)$.

Comment: My question about the second case

Comment: So how did you *get* those two answers.  Why you solving a quadratic inequality of something like that?

Answer (score 3):

To your first question

Yes.

If $x>2,$ then *obviously* $x\ge0$

Comment: OP asked multiple questions. Which are you answering? Is your yes an answer to "is this unnecessary?" Please be more specific. It may be clear to you but what about others?

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan there's no need to answer to the rest of his questions because their answer is implicitly in the 1st answer to his question

Comment: I was just asking to specify which question you were answering. Otherwise everything was fine.

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan ah. ok :)

Answer (score 1):

No this not right
the first interval is a special condition from the first one 
And we can't consider that If x>2  implies that x>=0

Comment: Thanks alot ,,, this is same as what I thought